# SpriteKit: How to draw a board of squares using SKSpriteNode with texture to be resolution independent?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I'm trying to draw a board of squares using SKSpriteNode using a texture. The board must have different various sizes (8x8, 12x15, etc.). This must be draw correctly independent of the device resolution. Figured the way in which to create the board, but the textures are not drawn correctly. Below is the code that loads the grid:

```
for (int y = 0; y < self.boardHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < self.boardWidth; x++) {
        SKSpriteNode *squareNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:_textureSquare];
        CGPoint squareCoordinate = CGPointMake(x, y);
        squareNode.position = [_squareSystemCoord tileCenter:squareCoordinate];
        squareNode.texture = _textureNormal;
        [self addChild:squareNode];
    }
}
```

_squareSystemCoord converts from square grid coords (i.e. (0,1), (1,2), etc) to SpriteKit coords system.

Due to the fact that SKSpriteNode takes the dimensions of the texture, the squares are drawn apart from each other on bigger resolutions.

Is there a way to draw a board of SKSpriteNode with texture to be resolution independent?

Thank you!

Comment: The sizes in SpriteKit are point sizes not pixel sizes. If you draw something at 100x100 on retina device it will be the same physical size as it is on a standard device. It will just have 4 times the number of pixels. How are you loading the grid. Can you show some code.

Comment: You can find the code below:
    for (int y = 0; y < self.boardHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < self.boardWidth; x++) {
            SKSpriteNode *squareNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:_textureSquare];
            squareNode.squareCoordinate = CGPointMake(x, y);
            squareNode.position = [_squareSystemCoord tileCenter:squareNode.squareCoordinate];
            squareNode.texture = _textureNormal;
            [self addChild:squareNode];
        }
    }
_squareSystemCoord converts from square grid coord to SKScene coords

Comment: Hmm... Can you show a screen shot of your problem? A comparison of standard vs retina. Also, could you show your `tileCenter` please.

Comment: Found +spriteNodeWithTexture:size: method in SKSpriteNode class reference. It seems to be what I was looking for. Will give it try and get back...

Comment: `spriteNodeWithTexture` should be all you need. That will then take the correct size based on the texture.

Comment: Tested with +spriteNodeWithTexture:size and it is working now. The texture will scale to fill the size of the node specified as parameter to the method mentioned above. Thanks for your first comment Fogmeister. It lead me to the solution.

Comment: These comments need to be converted to an answer, preferably by Fogmeister.